# all keys on my HP Envy are unresponsive

Tags: keyboard, hp-envy, unresponsive

All keys on my HP Envy laptop have stopped working. I can't even enter my password to log in.
All articles are telling me to try different things, but they all involve going into settings or device manager. Not able to do that with no keys on my laptop working!  I've tried plugging in an external keyboard, but that is also unresponsive.

Comment: Is Caps Lock turned on?

Comment: not sure, I can't even log into windows, unable to enter my password with keys not working

Comment: Is the light on your Caps Lock key on your keyboard `on` or `off`?

Comment: caps lock is off

Comment: Start with a bootable USB Key or Start in BIO (UEFI).   Do the keys work this way?

Comment: I'm not sure what your telling me to do. I'm not very computer savvy!

Comment: Given your level of computer knowledge and experience, I highly recommend that you take your computer to a local computer technician for support. The issue may be simple, it may be software, or it may be hardware. Regardless, someone who can physically look at the computer will be better able to help you well.

Comment: so there are no simple suggestions to be given that I can try before taking it to a repair shop?